# How do I return the data from S3 bucket in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I would like main() to return the data instead of just console logging it as shown below. How do I do it?

```
async function main() {
  // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
  var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  // Set the region
  AWS.config.update({ region: "REGION" });

  // Create S3 service object
  s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });

  // Call S3 to list the buckets
  s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try awaiting the `listBuckets` function.

Change

```js
s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

to

```js
return await s3.listBuckets();
```

---

If that doesn't work, you can always just construct a manual `Promise` and resolve it with the data.

```js
async function main() {
  // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
  var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  // Set the region
  AWS.config.update({ region: "REGION" });

  // Create S3 service object
  s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: "2006-03-01" });

  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Call S3 to list the buckets
    s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
main();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, it returns properties that are not useful at the moment. I'm interested in returning the data in the callback function.

Comment: @Gerald see updated answer